# Why I'm getting this error when deleting a row in DataGridView control?

Tags: c#, winforms

Why I'm getting this error when deleting a row in DataGridView control?
How can I address this issue?

```
Rows cannot be programmatically removed unless the DataGridView is data-bound to an IBindingList that supports change notification and allows deletion.
```

---

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<Person> person = new List<Person>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void Form1Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            person.Add(new Person("McDonalds", "Ronald"));
            person.Add(new Person("Rogers", "Kenny"));          
            dataGridView1.DataSource = person;
        }

        void BtnDeleteClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`List<T>` does not implement `IBindingList`,

```
public class List<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, 
    IEnumerable<T>, IList, ICollection, IEnumerable
```

You need to use a class that implements `IBindingList`

Use a [`BindingList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx) or [`DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) instead

Comment: so instead of List<Person>, do I have to make it something BindingList<Person>?

Comment: Thank you and Google. Just ran into this error now :)

Comment: Thank you very much for this life saver answer.

Answer (score 3):

You have to remove an element from the `person` list.

```
person.RemoveAt(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
void BtnDeleteClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    person.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index);
}
```