# Delete a row added manually

Tags: c#, datagridview, rows

I have a gridview and I add the rows to my datagridview with this code:

```
foreach(var docArticulo in listaArticulo)
{
    dgvArticulos.Rows.Add(docArticulo.RazonSocial, docArticulo.RazonSocialProveedor, docArticulo.CodArea, docArticulo.DescripcionArticulo, docArticulo.UnidadMedida, docArticulo.Cantidad, docArticulo.PrecioUnitario, docArticulo.Importe);
}
```

I added the rows manually because I want the edit some cells and if I use datagridview.DataSource I cant do it. But now I want to delete a row and the visual studio show me this message:

> Rows cannot be programmatically removed unless the DataGridView is data-bound to an IBindingList that supports change notification and allows deletion.

So far, I'm trying to delete using the following code:

```
if (dgvArticulos.CurrentRow != null)
{
    int index = dgvArticulos.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
    dgvArticulos.Rows.RemoveAt(index);
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Select a row", "Warning");
}
```

Does anyone know how to delete this kind of rows?

Comment: `DataGridView` has `AllowUserToDeleteRows` property. Set it to `true` and then try.

Comment: Same message @mmushtaq

Comment: maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395527/why-im-getting-this-error-when-deleting-a-row-in-datagridview-control